# Unescaped xml character

Tags: javascript, xml, escaping

My IDE (`phpstorm`) complains that this contains an `Unescaped xml character`.
This has been bugging me for a while:

```
<? } if (isset($_GET[id])) { ?>
    document.getElementById("facebook_likebutton").innerHTML = '<';
<? } ?>
```

it marks the `'<'` as the part where its an error.

see this image:

[image]

Comment: Speculation: It doesn't like you use of deprecated short open tags for PHP: `<?` should be `<?php`.

Answer (score 22):

Change

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and the error will be gone.

[source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10162)

Comment: (the latter is HTML5)

Answer (score 9):

Change the inspection settings as follow:

1. go to settings Ctrl+Alt+S
2. go to Editor>Inspections>HTML
3. uncheck Malformed content of "script" tag , or keep it checked and change the Severity (Red box) from Error to Warning or Weak Warning.

Answer (score 2):

the simple answer was that it didnt like having a `<` sign inside the `<script>` tag